# Does Hibernate support the limit statement in MySql?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm

I am working on a project which uses Java,MySql,Struts2 MVC and Hibernate. I tried using limit statement in hql query but its not working properly.

```
Select t from table1 t where t.column1 = :someVal limit 0,5
```

EDIT: I am using this as a namedQuery and calling this namedQuery using JPA Template

This works correctly in MySql but when I ran this as a hql query this returns all records without regard to limit statement. Has anyone faced the same problem?? Any help appreciated!!

Regards, RDJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use hibernates functions for paging! setFirstResult(), setMaxResults()

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t63849.html

Answer (score 1):

use `Query.setMaxResults(..)`

Comment: I am using NamedQuery . Can the functions setFirstResult() and setMaxResults() work with namedQuery??

Comment: Why don't you try reading the javadoc, or open the auto-complete in your IDE and see?

Answer (score 0):

I think,
If we use Criteria we can specify

> Crietria c=session.createCriteria(Emp.class);
>   c.setFirstResult(0);
>   c.setMaxResult(5);
>   List list=c.list();

Here 0 and 5 works as limit 0,5

Source : http://www.javatpoint.com/hcql

Answer (score -1):

```
    List<Employee> dataList = null;
    Query hQuery = null;

    try {
        // Getting Session

        hSession = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        hTransaction = hSession.beginTransaction();
        hQuery = hSession.getNamedQuery(query);

                    Iterator<Object> hIterator = paramMap.entrySet().iterator();

                    while (hIterator.hasNext()) {

     Map.Entry<String, Object> paramPair = (Map.Entry<String,Object>) hIterator.next();    

 hQuery.setParameter(paramPair.getKey(), paramPair.getValue());

        }

        hQuery.setFirstResult(1);
        hQuery.setMaxResults(100);

        System.out.println(hQuery);
        dataList = hQuery.list();

        hTransaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        hTransaction.rollback();


    } finally {
        try {
            hSession.flush();
            HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
        } catch (Exception hExp) {}
```

Comment: This is just a bunch of code. Some explanation as to how this helps the OP's concrete issue would be nice

Comment: you can find two methods `setFirstResult(),setMaxResults()` in `Query` interface which help to get the record in pagination..